# What is the behaviour of `ferror(FILE *)` and `std::ferror(FILE *)` when passed invalid pointers?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, std, libc

**What is the behavior of `::ferror(FILE *)` and `std::ferror(FILE *)` when passed invalid pointers?**

The C++ standards just refer to C (see [draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/cstdio.syn#1)). But in the C standard there is no mention under the `ferror` function description about what happens when an invalid pointer or `NULL` is passed.

I understand that according to C draft [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) §7.21.3.4:

> The value of a pointer to a `FILE` object is indeterminate after the associated file is closed (including the standard text streams).

But this should not prevent implementations for checking whether any given `FILE *` pointer (indeterminate or not) refers to valid `FILE` object.¹

Either way, the standards even seems to be silent about whether this is undefined behavior, implementation defined or something else.

---

¹ For example `fopen()` could store the returned pointer in some global set (e.g. `std::set<FILE *>`), `ferror()` and similar functions can then check whether their argument is contained in that set, and additionally `fclose()` would remove it from that set.

Comment: If the standard is silent on what happens when an invalid pointer, or a `NULL` pointer, is passed then the behaviour is undefined.   The definition of "undefined" in the standard also explicitly includes cases where the standard doesn't describe constraints on what happens.   It is certainly not true that behaviour is undefined only if the standard explicitly states it is undefined.

Comment: Passing an indeterminate value to a library function causes undefined behaviour

Comment: The behavior in this situation is the increased likelyhood of [demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). If you don't want demons come flying out of your nose, don't pass an invalid pointer to a library function, that's it.

Answer (score 6):

According to C draft [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) §4.2 omissions are considered undefined behavior (emphasis added):

> If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined. Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or **by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior**. There is no difference in emphasis among these three; they all describe ‘‘behavior that is undefined’’.

Thanks to [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706785/peter) for describing this in a comment to the question.

Comment: The C11 standard explicitly states that the behaviour is undefined: in C11 [§7.1.4 Use of library functions ¶1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4) — _Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated otherwise …: If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program, or a null pointer, or …), the behavior is undefined._

Answer (score 3):

It is undefined behavior. According to the C Standard (J.2 Undefined behavior)

> — The value of a pointer to a `FILE` object is used after the associated
>   file is closed  (7.21.3).

Answer (score 2):

> What is the behaviour of {any standard library function} when passed invalid pointers?

Some functions do check for `NULL`.  None are specified to check for other invalid pointers.   It is *Undefined behavior* as the C spec lacks any definition in these cases.

> But this should not prevent implementations for checking whether any given FILE * pointer (indeterminate or not) refers to valid FILE object.

This is true - a check is not prevented.  `ferror()` *could* perform such a check - yet it is not required to do so.  The behavior with such a pointer   is not *defined*.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant text is 7.1.4 *Use of library functions*, ¶1:

> Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow: **If an argument to a function has an invalid value** (such as a value outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program, or a null pointer, or a pointer to non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not const-qualified) or a type (after promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of arguments, **the behavior is undefined**.

For all standard library functions, passing a pointer which is null or otherwise invalid is undefined behavior unless the specification of that function provides a definition for it. However, in general, specification for use of a resource handle after the resource handle has been released is **fundamentally impossible to specify in a meaningful way** except by disallowing resource handles to ever be used again. So while it's possible to specify behavior for the null case and a few functions do, it's impossible to specify behavior for what happens for any form of UAF (use after free), of which use of `FILE *` after `fclose` is a case.

Comment: This is the relevant information for C — it is explicitly stated that the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

> > The value of a pointer to a FILE object is indeterminate after the associated file is closed (including the standard text streams).
>
> But this should not prevent implementations for checking whether any given FILE * pointer (indeterminate or not) refers to valid FILE object.

Unfortunately, no.  Imagine an implementation where the skeletons of `fopen` and `fclose` look like this...

```
FILE *
fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *fp = malloc(sizeof(FILE));
    if (!fp) return 0;
    // ... initialize fp ...
    return fp;
}

int
fclose(FILE *fp)
{
    // ... tear down fp ...
    free(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

In order to determine whether the argument to `ferror` refers to a valid FILE object, this implementation would have to be able to detect pointer values that *used to* refer to storage allocated by `malloc`, but are now indeterminate because that block of heap has already been freed.  As you probably already know, there is no way to do this.  Therefore, this implementation cannot do what you want, and the C committee did not want to rule out this implementation.

(The C standard consistently uses "indeterminate" to refer to values that you can't do *anything* with, except maybe copy them around; any control or arithmetic dependency on an indeterminate value provokes undefined behavior.  [Footnote: this is technically not supported by a close reading of the normative text of the standard, but all—literally all—implementations of C treat the sentence "The behavior is undefined if ... the value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate" in non-normative Annex J.2 of C11 as if it were normative, and also as if the "with automatic storage duration" qualifier were absent.])

Comment: Accessing the value of a variable with indeterminate value causes undefined behaviour.   That means it is not possible to "copy them around".   Accessing the value of a variable is part of the process of copying the value.

Comment: @Peter Thus I wrote "except _maybe_" rand not just "except".  Some compilers, as an extension, allow copying of indeterminate values (the destination becomes indeterminate as well) but not any other action on indeterminate values.

Comment: The idea I had was that `fopen()` could store the returned pointer in a global set (e.g. `std::set<FILE *>`), `ferror()` and similar functions can check whether their argument is contained in that set, and additionally `fclose()` would remove it from that set.

Comment: @zwol "except maybe" implies that copying such values around is okay.   It's not.   It is undefined behaviour.     The fact that compilers may allow something does not make it somehow acceptable or safe to do.   The fact you are going out of your way to make such a statement means you are encouraging people to deem it okay.

Comment: @Peter If I hadn't put that qualifier in, I would have been yelled at by people who are absolutely and unshakeably convinced that the Standard _does_ license people to copy indeterminate values (because it works on their compiler, and because the normative text actually does allow reading an indeterminate value as long as its type has no documented trap representations).  *shrug* Can't win sometimes.